# Solve quadratic equations without individually specifying cofficients

Tags: matlab, equation, fractions, equation-solving, quadratic

I am trying to solve equations like:

```
3*(3x-12)/(x+3)-2*(2x+3)/(3x-1) = 5
```

This is the code that I use:

```
eqn1 = 3*(3*X-12)/(X+3)-2*(2*X+3)/(3*X-1) == 5;
sol = solve(eqn1, X);
xSol = sol.X
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Error using sym/subsref
Too many output arguments.
```

Comment: Please explain what changes between your equations (give some examples of different possibilities). How do you get the inputs? As a vector of coefficients? As a symbolic string? Do you expect to get all possible solutions or just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I'd suggest is performing a graphical solution:

```
% Define the function:
f = @(X)3*(3*X-12)./(X+3)-2*(2*X+3)./(3*X-1)-5;
% Plot the function (solve graphically):
x = -30:0.1:30;
figure(); plot(x,f(x)); grid on; grid minor;
```

[image: Crude plot]

This function has vertical asymptotes and a horizontal asymptote, at `x=-3`, `x=1/3` and `y=8/3` (finding this is left as an exercise to the reader). Let's add them to the chart and zoom to the y-vicinity of 0:

```
hold on; plot([-3, -3, NaN, 1/3, 1/3], 600*[-1, 1, NaN, -1, 1],'--r');
plot([-30, 30], 8/3*[1 1], '--m'); ylim([-10 10]);
```

[image: Zoom in with asymptotes]

There appear to be two solution, one between the vertical asymptotes and another to the right of the right asymptote. We can define these regions for `fzero`:

```
% Find zeros:
z = [ fzero(f, [-3+eps(3) 1/3-eps(1/3)] ),... First solution
      fzero(f, [1/3+eps, 30])];             % Second solution
```

(where `30` is some sufficiently large number) and we get:

```
z =

    0.1902   21.6848
```